# kshell UNIX base directory

Tags: unix, ksh

I am trying to understand the following lines of kshell script. Can anyone please explain why we need a dot and space in the third line?

```
#!/bin/ksh
export scriptDir=${0%/*}
. $scriptDir/version.profile
echo "JAVA_HOME_FOR_THIS_SCRIPT=$JAVA_HOME"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.` command, which can also be written as `source`, is a built-in command in ksh and other sh-derived shells. In this case, it executes the commands contained in `$scriptDir/version.profile` in the context of the current shell process.

Quoting the ksh man page:

> `. name [ arg ... ]`
>    If  *name*  is a function defined with the **`function`** *name* reserved word
>   syntax, the function is executed in the current environment (as if it
>   had been defined with the *name*() syntax.)  Otherwise
>                 if *name* refers to a file, the file is read in its entirety and the commands are executed in the current shell
>   environment.  The search path specified by **PATH** is used  to  find  the
>   directory
>                 containing  the  file.   If any arguments *arg* are given, they become the positional parameters while processing the **.**  command
>   and the original positional parameters are restored upon comple‐
>                 tion.  Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.  The exit status is the exit status of the last command
>   executed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I know that export scriptDir=${0%/*} basically gives current directory, is it possible for you to explain the line of script?

Comment: Your question was about the `.` command. As for `${0%/*}`, I think it gives you the directory where the script lives, *not* the current directory. `$0` is the command name, and I think the `%/*` syntax strips the trailing component -- so if the script is `/home/username/bin/fred`, it strips the `/fred` leaving just the directory name. The ksh manual should explain it.